# Calculating a products profit loss based on price change (running counts)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having some difficulties calculating a products profit loss, based on price changes that have occurred throughout a period. I'm stuggling to calculate the loss when the price both increases and decreases throughout the period.

**Example:**

```
/*Create Table*/
CREATE TABLE #StoreSales
(
    SalesDate date,
    ProductCode int,
    Retail decimal(5,2),
    Quantity int
);

/*Insert Sales data into Temp Table*/
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-01',1264,'47.96',4);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-02',1264,'47.96',4);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-03',1264,'11.99',1);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-03',1264,'11.99',1);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-04',1264,'5.99',1);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-04',1264,'11.99',1);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-05',1264,'22.99',1);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-06',1264,'35.97',3);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-07',1264,'22.99',1);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-07',1264,'23.98',2);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-08',1264,'11.99',1);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-08',1264,'91.96',4);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-09',1264,'11.99',1);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-10',1264,'45.98',2);
INSERT INTO #StoreSales (SalesDate,ProductCode,Retail,Quantity) VALUES ('2014-11-11',1264,'11.99',1);


/*Query Temp Table*/
DECLARE @s date, @e date
SET @s = '2014-11-01'
SET @e = '2014-11-30';

SELECT  x.SalesDate
        ,x.ProductCode
        ,(x.Retail/nullif(x.Quantity,0)) as Current_Retail
        ,x.Quantity
        ,x.Retail as total_sales
    
FROM    #StoreSales x

WHERE   x.ProductCode = 1264
AND     x.SalesDate between @s and @e

ORDER BY x.SalesDate

DROP TABLE #StoreSales
```

**Results:**

```
SalesDate    ProductCode  Current_Retail     Quantity    total_sales
----------  ----------- -----------------  ----------  ------------
2014-11-01     1264           11.99             4           47.96
2014-11-02     1264           11.99             4           47.96
2014-11-03     1264           11.99             1           11.99
2014-11-03     1264           11.99             1           11.99
2014-11-04     1264           5.99              1           5.99
2014-11-04     1264           11.99             1           11.99
2014-11-05     1264           22.99             1           22.99
2014-11-06     1264           11.99             3           35.97
2014-11-07     1264           22.99             1           22.99
2014-11-07     1264           11.99             2           23.98
2014-11-08     1264           11.99             1           11.99
2014-11-08     1264           22.99             4           91.96
2014-11-09     1264           11.99             1           11.99
2014-11-10     1264           22.99             2           45.98
2014-11-11     1264           11.99             1           11.99
                                               ----        ---------
                                                28          417.72
```

In the above scenario, I need to find what the price SHOULD be at the time of the sale.

In order to do this, I need to join it to the retail table.

```
/* Retail Table */

ProductCode     ValidFrom         ValidTo          Retail 
----------     ------------     -------------    ----------              
   1264         2014-11-01       2014-11-04        11.99          
   1264         2014-11-05          NULL           22.99
```

As you can see from above, any sales between the following dates should have a retail of:

- 2014-11-01 should be 11.99
- 2014-11-05 to TODAY should be 22.99

> So the difficulty is comparing the RETAIL table, with the StoreSales table, checking if the retail matches, if not then calculate loss.

e.g.

> Sales should be (11.99 * 12) + (22.99 * 9) = 511.72.
>
> Actual sales was 417.72
>
> Loss = 94

**Result trying to obtain**

```
ProductCode       Loss
-------------   ---------
   1264           94.00
```

Any assistance would be fantastic

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to know the difference if all the sales were made at the highest price.  You can calculate this as:

```
select ProductCode,
       ( max(s.Current_Retail) * sum(s.quantity) - sum(total_sales) ) as loss
from #StoreSales s
group by ProductCode;
```

Or:

```
select ProductCode,
       ( max(s.Current_Retail) * sum(s.quantity) - sum(s.Current_Retail * s.quantity) ) as loss
from #StoreSales s
group by ProductCode;
```